# Document scaled when printing raw data

Tags: c#, printing, wmi, postscript

I'm trying to print pdf file directly on printer, which supports postscript. Unfortunately printed document is scaled (little smaller than print from adobe reader, with scaling mode - "Actual size").
Is there any way to print it without scaling?
Here is a code, which I'm using to print:

```
  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1401:PInvokesShouldNotBeVisible"), DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);


    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string pdfFileName, string printerName, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            bool success = false;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfFileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                int nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);

                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
                bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);

                IntPtr ptrUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
                ptrUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);

                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptrUnmanagedBytes, nLength);

                success = SendBytesToPrinter(printerName, ptrUnmanagedBytes, nLength, name);

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrUnmanagedBytes);
            }
            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool success = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = name;
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        success = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            if (success == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

By the way - can I manage printer margins, when I'm printing like that?

Thanks,
Bartosz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for advice @KenS,
finally I've found a solution why PDF's not printing properly. There was a problem with default PDF scaling, which is trying to fit print to page. Solution for this is to set scaling:

```
/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>
```

in PDF file, for example:

object before:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type/Catalog
/Pages 3
>>
endobj
```

object after:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type/Catalog
/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>
/Pages 3
>>
endobj
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF and PostScript are not the same thing! Just because your printer 'supports PostScript' doesn't mean it can print PDF files.

In this case it does look like your printer does support PDF printing. There are two possible reasons that spring to mind for scaling the output:

1) The media size of the PDF file does not match the media in the printer.

2) The printer has unprintable margins. In order to ensure that the entirety of the PDF file is printed (in case it contains drawing operations right up to the edge of the media), the printer scales the PDF so that the PDF media fits into the printable area of the printed media.

You can check the media size of the PDF page(s) against the media in your printer. If they match then you know its not that.

Solutions depend pretty much entirely on the capabilities of your printer. It may be you can tell it not to scale the output (if you are certain that the marked area of the PDF will fit in the printable area of the printed page). If not then your only solution is to remake the PDF file with a smaller media.

You could also try setting a CropBox in the PDF file which is smaller than the printed media and see if your printer will then print the PDF unscaled.